# MVC route issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this route registered:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Book",
                "book/{id}",
                new { action = "index", controller = "book" },
                new string[] { "Web.Areas.Books.Controllers" }
            );
```

This serves url like this:
http:///book/4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7

Now I have a url which is either of the following:

```
http://<domain>/book/4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7/GetFullDescription?app=3
OR
http://<domain>/book/GetFullDescription?app=3&id=4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7
```

I prefer the first route. I just can't make it work.
I have an action GetFullDescription defined in the book controller.

If I register a route like this, it gets to the GetFullDescription action.

```
context.MapRoute(
                "BookFullDesc",                
                "book/{action}/{id}",                
                new { action = "index", controller = "book", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "Web.Areas.Books.Controllers" }
            );
```

But the `http://<domain>/book/4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7` url breaks

unless I change it to
`http://<domain>/book/index/4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7` <-- Note index after index

**EDIT:**
ALL I WANT IS A SINGLE ROUTE TO SERVE BOTH OF THESE 2 URLS:

```
http://<domain>/book/4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7
http://<domain>/book/4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7/GetFullDescription
```

Thanks

Comment: Give your second route, the router is going to be looking for an action method called `4f6be481e8f6ae0a9063afe7` - I doubt that's what you're after.

Comment: That is the id value for the book. I have lots of books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Book",
                "book/{id}/{action}",
                new { action = "index", controller = "book", app = 3 },
                new string[] { "Web.Areas.Books.Controllers" }
            );
```

Comment: will this create problem in future if I need to add more urls under  book?

Comment: It is possible but you see now how to deal with these situation (i have made an edit to my answer by adding {action} in the pattern).

Comment: The situation is this: I have a book page. I have 7/8 different actions in the book controller. I need one route to server all of these actions (urls) and future urls. All of these url must have /book/id/action where the action is by default index if I don't specify anything after id.

Comment: There it is. Changed the GetFullDescription default action value to index and that's all.